# Nginx /foo and /foo/ redirects

Tags: amazon-ec2, servers, http

I want both http://domain/foo and http://domain/foo/ requests to serve a given resource. 
Here's the relevant part:

```
location / {
       rewrite /(.*) /ipns/QmdpoFuwY/$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

with this config only:

```
curl -X GET http://domain.io/foo/
```

returns a resource while:

```
curl -X GET http://domain.io/foo
```

gives a `Path Resolve` error.

Comment: What does the log indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could replace

```
rewrite /(.*) /ipns/QmdpoFuwY/$1 break;
```

with

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/]) /ipns/QmdpoFuwY/$1 break;
```

and try again.

The issue was solved by inspecting the logs. If for example one navigated to `/foo/` instead of `/foo/` the log indicated:

```
2017/10/15 14:51:28 [error] 7#7: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html/foo.html" is not found (20: Not a directory)
```

It turned out that the regex did not match `/foo/`. One could also enable the rewrite logging to facilitate debugging:

```
rewrite_log on;
```

Comment: I did:

  if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)[/]$) {
    rewrite /(.*)   rewrite /(.*) /ipns/QmdpoFuwY/$1 break;
  }

  if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)[^/]$) {
    rewrite /(.*) /ipns/QmdpoFuwY/$1/ break;
  }

The suggested answer should also work and is less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx code is incorrect, for example, because you're effectively losing the extra functionality afforded by http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect default value of `default`.

As per the documentation at http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass, the correct way would be to map location on the front-end and back-end directly within the `proxy_pass`, especially if you don't need to be using any variables:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipns/QmdpoFuwY/;
}
```

---

Otherwise, back to your question, there is absolutely no reason to have `/foo` and `/foo/` point to the same resource.

In fact, it would be perfectly legal for one to be internally expanded to `/foo.html`, whereas for the other to `/foo/index.html`, so, the fact that different results are returned is entirely normal, and doesn't need to be fixed.